# how to transform multiple XML files in StreamSource

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transformation, apache-fop

I am trying to do the `XSLT` transformation of multiple `XML` files. The basic requirement is to create a single `PDF` using all the `XMLs`
It is working for a single file. But how to do same for multiple files.

For single file:

```
File xsltFile = new File(TEMP_DIR + "//pattern.xsl");
StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(new File(INPUT_DIR + "//input_1.xml"));
.
.
.
transformer.transform(streamSource , result); // results in one PDF.
```

Now i have several `input_[i].xmls`.

How to perform `XSLT` transformation?

Comment: What is stopping you just doing the above in a loop?

Comment: We really would need to see the XSLT, at least see its entry point, as well as the structure of those XML inputs. Furthermore tell us whether the XSLT processor you use (with Java?) is an XSLT 1.0 processor (like Xalan or like Saxon 6) or an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 as in the latter case there are more options to write a single stylesheet to process multiple documents at once, for instance using the `collection` function.